# Getting some error while installing Hudson?

Tags: java, hudson, hudson-plugins

After Installing Hudson i got the below error message.

Can anyone help me how to fix the error.

Error:

```
[!] Error

org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: maven2-moduleset
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.executeReactor(Hudson.java:719)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.hudson.init.InitialRunnable.run(InitialRunnable.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: maven2-moduleset
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2263)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at hudson.model.TopLevelItemsCache.get(TopLevelItemsCache.java:96)
    at hudson.model.LazyTopLevelItem.item(LazyTopLevelItem.java:144)
    at hudson.model.LazyTopLevelItem.hasPermission(LazyTopLevelItem.java:271)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.getItems(Hudson.java:1303)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.getItems(Hudson.java:223)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.getAllItems(Hudson.java:1367)
    at hudson.model.Hudson$12.run(Hudson.java:2481)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at hudson.model.Hudson$4.runTask(Hudson.java:699)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: maven2-moduleset
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:143)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1034)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:76)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1018)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:894)
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:115)
    at hudson.model.TopLevelItemsCache$1.load(TopLevelItemsCache.java:81)
    at hudson.model.TopLevelItemsCache$1.load(TopLevelItemsCache.java:75)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    ... 18 more
```

Powered by Hudson Open Source Continuous Integratio

Regards,

Sudhansu

Comment: Seems to me like its not able to read some xml file, probably pom.xml file as the error is related to maven.

Answer (score 3):

I adjusted the config's on my Hudson server and started popping this error immediately after.

I had to do the following to resolve the error:

1. Shutdown Hudson
2. Move the jobs directory to a non-hudson location (like my home directory)
3. Start Hudson
4. Manage Hudson -> Manage Plugins -> Enable Maven 2 plugin -> Save
5. Shutdown Hudson
6. Move the jobs directory back into place*
7. Restart Hudson

(If you know specific jobs that are Maven2-based, then you can just move these jobs out of the jobs directory).

hth